# Site Column as lookupfield creates false URL-Strings

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, asp.net, site-column

I have a created a custom site column, which is a lookup field, on my rootsite.
However, I use this colum now on a subsite in another list. The idea is, to have a central list with lets say Divisions, which I can use on every subsite.

The funny thing is, the NewForm.aspx shows me the content of the Divisions table:

[image]

After I create the new item the list looks just fine:

[image]

But, when I click one of the items in the column Divisions it runs into this error:

[image]

The error log says, that SharePoint couldn't find the list:

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: SPException 
Exception message: List does not exist.

The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListsWithCallback(String bstrUrl, Guid foreignWebId, String bstrListInternalName, Int32 dwBaseType, Int32 dwBaseTypeAlt, Int32 dwServerTemplate, UInt32 dwGetListFlags, UInt32 dwListFilterFlags, Boolean bPrefetchMetaData, Boolean bSecurityTrimmed, Boolean bGetSecurityData, Boolean bPrefetchRelatedFields, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter p2DWriter, Int32& plRecycleBinCount)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.EnsureListsData(Guid webId, String strListName)
```

What do you guys think is wrong here?

thanks for you help!

**EDIT:**

I found something which might be the issue but i don't have a clue how to solve it.

The link, which is created from the lookupcolumn, does not redirect to the other site! Sadly it stays on the same site i.e.

```
http://10.38.0.11/sites/Innofront/cc/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={e0f712a5-36f7-4c74-9b0a-7170c3b30e9e}&ID=2&RootFolder=*
```

the "/cc/" is the name of the subsite. The correct link would look like this:

```
http://10.38.0.11/sites/Innofront/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={e0f712a5-36f7-4c74-9b0a-7170c3b30e9e}&ID=2&RootFolder=*
```

Its the same link without the /cc/.

Does anyone have an idea or workaround for this mislinking?

**EDIT 2**

After installing the latest update of sharepoint the bug disappeared! Hope this helps!

greetings
Jürgen

Comment: I am facing exactly same issue. It has to be SP Bug, did you find the solution or workaround?

Comment: Sorry, I did nit find any solution to this - till now

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure on exact solution to this scenario but I believe you can implement it using Managed Metadata that fits better for what you are trying to do.

The following article describes step by step how to implement managed metadata, this way anyone can create a list that uses same set of values.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-a-managed-metadata-column-HA101631602.aspx

Comment: Thank you for that answer! It's a nice workaround but not the answer to my question. Anyway, i'll give you an upvote :)